# cast from SHDocVw.InternetExplorer to process

Tags: c#, .net, browser, shdocvw

Is it posible to cast from SHDocVw.InternetExplorer to process object?
i tried to cast like this but it didnt work:

```
Process p = (SHDocVw.InternetExplorer)IE
```